# Why 梱入 does not appear in any dictionary?

Tags: kanji, readings, dictionary

On a parcel that came from Japan, there is this sentence:

> お客様のご注文の品が梱入されております。

The meaning is clear: “There are customer’s goods in the package.”

What puzzles me though is, why I could’t find the word 梱入•する in any dictionary. I mean, スーパー大辞林, weblio, JMdict… none of those lists this word. (My bulky paper dictionary of Kanji doesn’t even contain 梱.) I am asking because there may be a reason for that. Like, is 〜入(れ)•する some kind of a productive suffix forming words with a meaning of „contained in ~“?

What’s the reading then? Is it こんにゅう, or possibly こりにゅう, こりいれ? The last one is what Yomikatawa says and it would mean irregular okurigana, but that’s not that uncommon. My Japanese keaboard fails to convert こんにゅう, with こりいれ I got at least to 梱入れ almost instantly.

Comment: 梱入 is not an uncommon term for today's business people who are involved in the logistics industry, but 青空文庫全文検索 and BCCWJ both have no example of it, so I think it's still in the early stage of general dissemination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, Japanese 熟語 (jukugo, word consisting of 2 or more kanjis) can easily be made by just juxtaposing kanjis, and sometimes this technique is used to shorten spelling. In this case, the word 梱入 is technical term used amongst wholesalers and therefore not in dictionaries. 梱入 is a jukugo-ish form of 梱包されて入っている (be packed and contained).

The reading is こんにゅう. Usually, those jukugos are read in chinese-derived reading 音読み (on-yomi). 梱 can be read as こり and this is 訓読み (readings based on words existed before kanjis were introduced), though.

Comment: Is it really an "abbreviation"? I think 梱入 is an abbreviation of nothing, just like 前進 is not an abbreviation of 前に進む. To say 梱入 is an abbreviation, it's full form should usually be a kanji-only compound, like 自由民主党 → 自民党.

Comment: I used the word "abbreviation" as "formal deletion of letters and concatenation of remnants". Of course, "abbreviation" sounds like casual and informal while making 和語 into 漢語 increases authority and formality. But, hey, can't the procedure of making 熟語 from a prosaic expression be regarded as abbreviation?

Comment: The "unabbreviated" form must be an established set phrase if you want to call something an abbreviation. Or are you saying `梱包されて入っている` is an existing set phrase that has been recognized by many people? Isn't it a phrase you've come up with today to explain 梱入? Again, just because 前進, 食事, 試用, 岩石 and so on can be explained with a prosaic expression does not mean they are abbreviations.

Comment: 日本語で失礼します。私が「梱入」を"abbriviation"と説明したのは、これが単なる業界用語であって、「梱包して入れること」を収まりのよい二字熟語に縮めたかったのだと思われたからです。"abbriviation"には省略、短縮の意味がありますが、私が用いたのは後者です。確かに「前進」や「試用」といった基本的な語彙を省略と見るのは、一般的な日本人の感覚では奇妙です。しかし、今回のように特殊な、「梱包して入れること」というフルセンテンスが念頭に置かれている状況では上のような短縮の過程が存在するとみてよいのではないでしょうか。辞典に載っていないということはその単語は一般的でないのですから、「梱」と「入」を直截結合したというよりは造語的な過程のもとで短縮されたと見る方が自然だと思われます。

Comment: @Qwert Would you be able to provide a resource, not necessarily a dictionary or anything formal, that would confirm the こんにゅう reading?

Comment: 私は梱入という語を大昔から知っており、「搬入」等と何ら本質的に変わらない単語だと感じており、`「梱包して入れること」というフルセンテンスが念頭に置かれている` とは微塵も感じないので、そこの認識の差なのかもしれません。私にとって「梱入」は、「分注」「刺入」「剛接」等と同じ、辞書になくとも特定の業界では長年当然に使われている「普通の漢語」なので。私の予想では「梱入は何の短縮形か?」と問われても、この語を日常に使っている大抵の人は「は?」となるとは思います。新しいか・辞書にあるかどうかで短縮形と呼ぶかどうかを決めるべきではないと思います。

Comment: @Glutexo Here is the link to yomikatawa.com. https://yomikatawa.com/kanji/%E6%A2%B1%E5%85%A5

Comment: @naruto 了解しました。私には「梱入」は意味は分かるがどこか耳慣れない単語でしたからそのように解釈してしまいました。すでに長年使っている方がいらっしゃるようですから、「梱包して入れること」の熟語化という理解でよいでしょうか。

Comment: はい、ごちゃごちゃ言ってすみませんでした。